# Troubles with a two column document using tufte-handout

Tags: two-column, tufte

I found a LaTeX minimal guide (originally written by Alan Munn), and trying to *translate it* at the `tufte-handout` class I have a problem. I use an abstract environment that uses the full textblock width, and below lists of packages used for different tasks displayed in two columns. My problem is that the second column crashes with the abstract body and I don't know how to fix it.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\Large \textbf{Summary}}

\begin{abstract}
\begin{fullwidth}
    This is a list of the packages that are in my opinion the most useful for writing papers and theses in linguistics. I have made no attempt to justify the choices, but I find almost all of these packages essential in my own work. The essential packages and the basic linguistics packages (relevant to your particular field) should probably be loaded in every document you write. Unless noted, all packages are part of \TeX{}Live and Mik\TeX{}.
\end{fullwidth}
\end{abstract}

\section{Essential packages} % (fold)
\label{sec:essential_packages}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{geometry} set margins and general page layout
        \item \texttt{inputenc} accented characters in your source1,2
        \item \texttt{fontenc} accented characters in your output3,4
        \item \texttt{fancyhdr} headers and footers
        \item \texttt{array} improved tables
        \item \texttt{booktabs} nice looking tables
        \item \texttt{multicol} multiple column text
        \item \texttt{graphicx} inclusion of graphics
        \item \texttt{natbib} bibliography and citations5           
    \end{itemize}
% section essential_packages (end)

\section{Packages for customizing the looks of things} % (fold)
\label{sec:packages_for_customizing_the_looks_of_things}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{titlesec} customization of all section titles
        \item \texttt{enumitem} customization of any list environment
        \item \texttt{setspace} double and 1.5 spacing
        \item \texttt{parskip} unindented paragraphs separated by blank lines
    \end{itemize}   
% section packages_for_customizing_the_looks_of_things (end)

\section{Font packages} % (fold)
\label{sec:font_packages}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{mathptmx} Times (New) Roman
        \item \texttt{mathpazo} Palatino
        \item \texttt{helvet}  Helvetica
    \end{itemize}

% section font_packages (end)   
\end{document}
```

I'm working with Sublime Text 2 and TeXlive 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remarks

You need to use the `multicol` package for this task, because this is the only one, which supports switching between one column and twocolumn reliably.

I didn't try it, but maybe you can also use `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn`. The downside is, that these macros will start a new page.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

{\Large \textbf{Summary}}

\begin{abstract}
    This is a list of the packages that are in my opinion the most useful for writing papers and theses in linguistics. I have made no attempt to justify the choices, but I find almost all of these packages essential in my own work. The essential packages and the basic linguistics packages (relevant to your particular field) should probably be loaded in every document you write. Unless noted, all packages are part of \TeX{}Live and Mik\TeX{}.
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Essential packages} % (fold)
\label{sec:essential_packages}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{geometry} set margins and general page layout
        \item \texttt{inputenc} accented characters in your source1,2
        \item \texttt{fontenc} accented characters in your output3,4
        \item \texttt{fancyhdr} headers and footers
        \item \texttt{array} improved tables
        \item \texttt{booktabs} nice looking tables
        \item \texttt{multicol} multiple column text
        \item \texttt{graphicx} inclusion of graphics
        \item \texttt{natbib} bibliography and citations5           
    \end{itemize}
% section essential_packages (end)

\section{Packages for customizing the looks of things} % (fold)
\label{sec:packages_for_customizing_the_looks_of_things}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{titlesec} customization of all section titles
        \item \texttt{enumitem} customization of any list environment
        \item \texttt{setspace} double and 1.5 spacing
        \item \texttt{parskip} unindented paragraphs separated by blank lines
    \end{itemize}   
% section packages_for_customizing_the_looks_of_things (end)

\section{Font packages} % (fold)
\label{sec:font_packages}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{mathptmx} Times (New) Roman
        \item \texttt{mathpazo} Palatino
        \item \texttt{helvet}  Helvetica
    \end{itemize}

% section font_packages (end)   
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. In fact is the same trick I used when I tried to make the same with Word (of course without packages). And it looks fine if before the `multicols`environment I use the `fullwidth` one. But is not a good choice to use more tahn one column if you need to add sidenotes, marginotes or footnotes. All them are composed in the right margin of the page.